# How can i speed-up my Visual basic application?

Tags: vb.net, performance, filereader

I have two lists (each list between 80000 and 200000 lines).
List1: List with OLD data like this: sku|price|stock
List2: List with NEW data like this: sku|price|stock

I now pick line 1 from list1, split that line into 3 textboxes (sku,price and stock). Next i use textbox1 and search for that sku in list2. When i found the line i grap it and split it into textboxes. Next i compare the prices and stock, do some calculations (extra stuff with more textboxes i won't mention to keep this post clean). If there are no changes in price or stock i put textboxes i created from line 1 from list1 together and put that line in a new file List3. If there are changes i use textboxes from the line i created from list2 and put that line to the List3 file.
All is working how it should, but not fast enough. I already sorted the lines from list1 and list2 so i don't have to cycle much lines to find the line i need. Also after each edit/compare i remove the lines used in list1 and list2 to make the list smaller and by doing this also faster. But still it aint fast enough.
What is not fast enough? I do tests with 25000 lines in list1 and list2. I have reached speeds like over 14000 per hour. But when i grow the lists over 100000 lines i only reach 4000 per hour. 14000 per hour is not fast enough but faster as 4000 per hour. (i'm no expert but i assume i can use visual basic to get better speeds)

Here comes some code i use to do the magic (like how i read and write files):

Timers: i think people will slap me for using them, but this is just how it works right now ;-)
Timer 1 will be used to grap the 1st line from list1 and split it. This is not time consuming and so not the problem, but here is some code from timer1:

```
Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
            fileReader =
            My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\file-with-old-prices-stock.txt")
            Dim stringReader As String
            stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
            TextBox1.Text = stringReader
            Dim myline As String
            Dim half() As String
            myline = TextBox1.Text
            half = myline.Split("|")
            TextBox1.Text = half(0)
            TextBox16.Text = half(1)
            TextBox17.Text = half(2)
```

Next i start timer2:
this is the complete timer2 code:

```
Timer2.Stop()

        Dim appPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Dim fileReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(appPath & "\file-with-new-prices-stock.txt")
        Dim fileContents() As String = fileReader.ReadToEnd.Split(ControlChars.Cr)
        TextBox3.Text = fileContents.Length
        Dim i As Integer
        Do Until i = "1"
            If TextBox7.Text = TextBox3.Text Then
                NumericUpDown1.Value = 1
                Timer2.Stop()
                i = "1"
            Else
                If fileContents(TextBox7.Text).Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
                    TextBox2.Text = fileContents(TextBox7.Text)
                    Dim myline As String
                    Dim half() As String
                    myline = TextBox2.Text
                    half = myline.Split("|")
                    TextBox4.Text = half(0)
                    TextBox5.Text = half(1)
                    TextBox6.Text = half(2)
                   If TextBox6.Text > "1" Then
                        TextBox6.Text = "1"
                    End If

                    CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                    fileReader.Close()

                    Do Until i = "1"

                        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
                        Dim fileInUse As Boolean = True

                        Try
                            'if Open() succeeds, then we know the file is not currently in use

                            fs = System.IO.File.Open(appPath & "\file-with-new-prices-stock.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)

                            fileInUse = False
                            fs.Close()

                            Dim linesList As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\file-with-new-prices-stock.txt"))

                            'Remove the line to delete, e.g.
                            linesList.RemoveAt(TextBox7.Text)

                            File.WriteAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\file-with-new-prices-stockTEMP.txt", linesList.ToArray())


                            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\file-with-new-prices-stockTEMP.txt", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\file-with-new-prices-stock.txt", True)
                            fileReader.Close()

                            Timer200.Start()
                            Timer2.Stop()
                            i = "1"
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try
                    Loop

                End If
                If Not fileContents(TextBox7.Text).Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then

                    TextBox7.Text = TextBox7.Text + 1
                    fileReader.Close()
                    Timer2.Start()
                End If
            End If
        Loop
```

So what i do is take textbox1.text and somehow find the line with that text in list2 (file-with-new-prices-stock.txt). This is the part that is to slow (or not coded the right way. what i assume).

Next i do magic with the 2 lines (i use a couple timers) and create a new line and append that line to list3 (that is working fine).

It is getting to slow when i cannot find the sku from list1 in list2. The application needs to read all lines, line by line. I have tried to just double the timers and split the files, but that way i just split the files and the application will be as slow/fast as before.

Solutions i found but cannot get them to work are backgroundworker and multi-treading. I use textboxes and get errors when i use those one of those 2 options. I don't want to completely rewrite my application if it is not needed. Maybe there is a faster way to pre-read the list2 file or not read the complete line when searching for a sku (like when sku starts with a "1" it will skip lines that starts with something else).

Love to see some suggestion that will show me the road i need to walk ;-)
Thanks!

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. If you're trying to somehow match `list1` and `list2` why are you using text boxes and timers?

Comment: Still using default designer control names? Doing math with strings? Come on step up your coding.

Comment: xxbbcc: i need to find changes in prices and stock levels. When i found the new prices and stock i compare them in textboxes (@DonA this is slowing down the application or you just want to slap a newbee?) @DonA when i don't use the standard control names and change them to fancy new ones it will speed-up my app? I just don't get it what you want to tell me. If you want to tell me to stop coding just tell me and why bother answer my question?

Comment: Generally dealing directly with control's properties is very slow. Save the values in dedicated variables and work with those. Update controls once at the end. You could also try to use Dictionaries to look up values quickly, or, what would probably be best, use real databases and database queries for such large datasets.

Comment: @Maarten Why are you using a timer? I tried finding its purpose in your code but it's not there.

Comment: @Maarten, we are a community and I feel it is worth mentioning so I did. Not converting types for math is bad practice. `TextBox6.Text > "1"` is using string comparison - do you want that vs integer comparison? Plus it has no meaning being `TextBox6.Text`.

Comment: This has to be the dirtiest way to track stuff - please learn how to use a database!

Comment: I agree with @Jens, aside from the Dictionary.  I think scanning pairs in a dictionary might be slower than iterating through a List Of String, and I also agree that a database is better for dealing with this.  Avoiding setting the text on textbox3 and just using the variable is also a good suggestion.  Also you might consider using `instr` with vbtextcompare if you are just matching text cuz contains is case sensitive.  And I am going to keep flagging @DonA on every comment he makes that berates the OP.  ;-)

Comment: If he want's to search just number a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Tuple(Of Decimal, Integer))` can be searched very fast (in a 1 million items dictionary a lookup still only takes 0.2 ms on my machine). I think this would work for his purposes well enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to improve the speed and readability of your code.

1. Using TextBoxes/whatever controls to hold your data will make it much slower. Use variables instead.
2. There is a [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class available.
3. The fixed element for each of your lines of data is the SKU. You can take advantage of the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) generic class by using the SKU as the key and the rest of the data as the value. The value can conveniently be held in an instance of a class.

I assume there is a chance of new SKUs being added in this simple example code:

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1


    Private Class ItemData
        Property Price As Decimal
        Property StockLevel As Integer
    End Class

     Private Sub GenerateTestData(filename As String, quantity As Integer, price As Decimal)
        ' Generate some test data. It is not at all sophisticated.

        Dim rand As New Random

        Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename)
            Dim skuNumber As Integer = quantity
            Dim sku As String

            For i = 1 To quantity
                sku = "A" & skuNumber.ToString()
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", sku, price, rand.Next(0, 101)))
                skuNumber -= 1
            Next

        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Function ReadData(filename As String) As Dictionary(Of String, ItemData)
        Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, ItemData)
        Using tfp As New TextFieldParser(filename)
            tfp.SetDelimiters({"|"})

            While Not tfp.EndOfData
                Dim parts = tfp.ReadFields()
                ' Make sure to convert the text input to the correct types.
                ' TODO: check there are three parts.
                ' TODO: make sure the price and stocklevel fields can be parsed.
                data.Add(parts(0), New ItemData With {.Price = CDec(parts(1)), .StockLevel = CInt(parts(2))})
            End While

        End Using

        Return data

    End Function

    Private Sub UpdateData(currentDataFile As String, updateDataFile As String, newDataFile As String)
        Dim currentData = ReadData(currentDataFile)
        Dim updateData = ReadData(updateDataFile)

        ' Update or add data.
        For Each item In updateData
            If currentData.ContainsKey(item.Key) Then
                currentData(item.Key) = item.Value
            Else
                currentData.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
            End If
        Next

        ' Write updated info to the new file.
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(newDataFile)
            For Each item In currentData
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", item.Key, item.Value.Price, item.Value.StockLevel))
            Next
        End Using

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim dataFolder = "C:\temp"
        Dim currentFile = Path.Combine(dataFolder, "currentData.txt")
        Dim updateFile = Path.Combine(dataFolder, "updateData.txt")

        GenerateTestData(currentFile, 100000, 5.99D)
        GenerateTestData(updateFile, 90000, 4D)

        Dim newFile = Path.Combine(dataFolder, "newData.txt")

        ' TODO: remove timing parts.
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()

        UpdateData(currentFile, updateFile, newFile)

        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine((sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000).ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

My computer ran that in well under one minute.